# ASP.NET / C# item.FileName

Tags: asp.net

litFiler.Text += [a class='group2' href='./references/big/'][img src=\"./references/small/" + item.FileName + "\" width=\"100\" /][/a][br /]";

WHERE TO PUT A **'+ item.FileName'** on the **a class 'group2'**, such as it is on :
[img src=\"./references/small/" + item.FileName + "\" width=\"100\" /]

i can figure where to put it, my colorbox will open the big pictures when i click them, right know the url on hover the small picture is "references/big/"